# Ng-class doesn't work

Tags: css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm working on an basic sidemenu-Ionic project... I have a variable in rootScope wich I use in the directive ng-class for my sidemenu-header bar and navigation bar, the problem is that `ng-class='myvar'` just works in menu's header but not in the main header. That is to say, the style just appears in the sidemenu, this is the [view](https://i.imgsafe.org/6ab23ec298.png).

However if a use `class={{myvar}}` the styles appear but they don't change when myvar is updated, here is my code:

---

```
<ion-side-menus>

  <ion-side-menu side="left">

            <!--**** This works**** -->
<ion-header-bar  ng-class="myvar">
  <h1 class="title">Menu</h1>
</ion-header-bar>

    <ion-content>
        <ion-list>
          ...
        </ion-list>
    </ion-content>

  </ion-side-menu>

  <ion-side-menu-content>

          <!--**** This doesn't work**** -->
    <ion-nav-bar ng-class="myvar" >
          <!--**** If i change it for class={{myvar}}, it doesn't refresh**** -->
             ...
    </ion-nav-bar>
    <ion-nav-view name="menuContent"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-side-menu-content>
</ion-side-menus>
```

---

EDIT: Here is a simplified [demo](https://codepen.io/Zgluis/pen/yavJRP), if you have another idea about how to approach this share it please.

For more information about my main problem please check my other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39854215/ionic-how-to-change-header-bar-style-with-a-variable)

Comment: Create a demo that reproduces problem. You are probably running into child scope issues and using an object might solve it but we don't know how you change it or where. See [mcve]. Also make sure to read the `ngClass` docs

Comment: Also, please use a title that is specific to your problem. I can assure you that `ng-class` works fine.

Comment: Thanks for answer, here is my demo: https://codepen.io/Zgluis/pen/yavJRP @charlietfl

Comment: What exactly does `myvar` contain…?

Comment: It contains "bar-positive" for example, please check my demo. @deceze

Comment: There is no indication in demo what steps need to be followed to see problem. That is hardly a simplified demo

Comment: Sorry about that, I updated the demo with some comments in the css side, please check it out @charlietfl

Comment: select user type doesn't work. I click it and nothing happens and then when i move mouse the sidebar shows up.

Comment: Are you sure? I tested the Select again and it works, remember to click in the word "positive" @charlietfl